# Recurring billing / profiles management system

Tags: looking-for-a-script, payments

As a company, we have various recurring fees which our clients pay. These can include:

- hosting plans
- maintenance agreements
- SLAs
- ...

I would like to know if anyone knows of a good, web-based recurring billing / payments management system which we could use to help us get more organised regarding this aspect of our business.  Basically, we would need to:

- Create recurring profiles, e.g. hosting, emails / domain services @ 200eur / year.
- Be able to give free / extend the subscription period, for any reason.

Also, we don't have specific products which we would like to choose and charge. All these recurring fees are discussed with the clients, and are created on a *per-client* basis.

I'm not sure if this is the best place to ask, however since I think most 'webmasters' require such a system to keep track of payment, I thought this would be the place to go for.

Answer (score 1):

**Try WHMCS**

Send your clients high quality professional looking invoices. PDF versions are attached to every invoice related email WHMCS sends, including new invoice notifications, and payment reminder notices, so your clients don’t even need to visit your site to view their bills. Plus invoices are fully customisable via templates.

You can have as much automation as you want. From automated setup, to welcome emails, to password changes, upgrades, suspensions, and more… WHMCS can handle it all. WHMCS is all about integration and automation, bringing together all the services you use into an easy to use combined single interface.

**Features**

Multiple Currencies,Quotes/Estimates,Tax Support,One Off & Recurring,any Integrated Payment Gateways,Credits System,Automated Reminders,Support Ticket Billing ,Late Fees

[Full Features Here](http://www.whmcs.com/features/)

Answer (score 0):

I know a datacenter that uses blusynergy (or something like that) for this type of billing, they had US and EUR support for contract specific recurring billing if I recall. HTH

Answer (score 0):

A great recurring billing service is Chargify who have excellent hosted pages as well as an API. You can configure a plan for each of your clients, add line items whenever they purchase an extra service in the future etc. They are PCI compliant and work with most popular gateways. They are not a merchant account but handle every recurring billing option and scenario you would need.

http://chargify.com

They allow you to setup a free developer/demo account without limits other than connecting to a live gateway.

Answer (score 0):

I will second the vote for WHMCS, its a really good billing system and has tons a features you will find very helpful.  A professional product that gets updated with new features regularly and I must say I really enjoy the benefits of the automation feature when working with monthly billing clients.

Check it out [www.whmcs.com](http://www.whmcs.com).

Comment: That link went to an affiliate program until I edited it. Please read the FAQ about promoting things that benefit you. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion